# How to Make A Twitter Bootstrap Modal Footer Always be Visible on Small Screens?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile, responsive-design, modal-dialog

Using Twitter Bootstrap 2.3.1, what changes need to be made in order to force the footer (and its contents!) to always be shown, even on smaller screens? I would expect that on these smaller screens, the content in the `modal-header` and `modal-footer` would always be shown, and the content of each fully shown, with only the contents of `modal-body` being scrollable. `modal-header` seems to behave this way currently, but `modal-footer` gets resized to the point that where on very small vertical-height screens, the footer is no longer even visible.

In this example, you can see that with a lot of `modal-body` content, the `modal-footer` on a very small screen is being truncated, where I would expect the button within it to be shown completely, as in the second partial example.

[image: Modal with truncated footer (actual behavior)]

[image: Modal with full footer (expected behavior)]

Answer (score 0):

The `.modal-body` class has `max-height: 400px` by default. You can overwrite in another CSS file (or edit Bootstrap LESS files) to a smaller value or set this value via javascript on page load and on resize, according with the window height.